# Can't get entity metadata to work in MVC 2 with VB.NET

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to use metadata to further define my entity objects using MVC2, LINQ to SQL, and VB.NET.  Here are the two main pieces of code in question:

```
<HiddenInput(DisplayValue:=False)> _
    <Column(IsPrimaryKey:=True, IsDbGenerated:=True, AutoSync:=AutoSync.OnInsert)> _
    Public Property ItemID As Integer
        Get
            Return _itemID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _itemID = value
        End Set
    End Property

        <DataType(DataType.MultilineText)> _
    <Column()> _
    Public Property Description As String
        Get
            Return _description
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _description = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Here's the code for my view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.ItemID) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.ItemID) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ItemID) %>
        </div>

 <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Description) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Description) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Description) %>
        </div>
```

For the first example, my Create View is supposed to render the input tag 'hidden' in the resulting html.  In the second example, my Create View is supposed to render a larger input text field for description, because of the  metadata and the  metadata, respectively.  However, neither occurs.

The first thing that comes to mine is that maybe I am defining metadata in VB.NET syntactically inappropriately.  All of my examples of defining metadata are in C#... I can find absolutely zero examples in VB.NET.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.TextBoxFor()` **always** renders a visible text box. Hence the name. :)

To have a different kind of editor based on the attributes, use `Html.EditorFor()` instead.